# What's the difference between these two names?

Tags: translation, pronunciation

オタ

オター

I want a name translated but not sure which to pick, what sounds the best and what's the difference between them? The name which I'm trying to translate is "Oter".

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is オター. That horizontal bar after タ is a [long vowel marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu), which indicates the vowel of the "ter" part should be pronounced longer than usual. Usually Japanese people prefer a long vowel for the "-er" and "-ar" sound at the end of a short name, for example コナー "Conar", ケラー "Keller". In addition, オタ is often used as an abbreviation of [オタク](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otaku), so it may carry an undesirable connotation.